# vscode not showing missing props error when importing vue component dynamically

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

- When i am importing a vue component dynamically vscode doesn't show any errors for missing props.
  [image]
- When importing the component, vscode throws error properly.
  [image]
- Here is the code for the child component.

```
<template>
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name!: string;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What VS Code plugins are you using for Vue templates?

Comment: Using vetur on vscode.